# Really struggling to understand this for loop from django tutorial

Tags: python

I really don't understand this for loop:

```
 output = ', '.join([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list])
```

I understand what `for q in latest_question_list` is doing. But im used to then having a code block underneath, not in front of the loop.

I don't understand how exactly this works or what it is even called to search it lol.

Comment: list comprehension

Comment: ok ill google that

Comment: it is first creating a list of text and then joining those text with `,  `

Comment: for every question (called `q`) in `latest_question_list` (seems to be a list of questions), get the text (`q.question_text` ) and put it in a list (that's what the `[q.question_text......]` mean). Then you have a list of questions texts, and join them with `', `.

suppose that you have latest_question_list with 2 questions with text `lates_question_list[0].question_text = 'why?` and `lates_question_list[0].question_text = 'where?` Then you get the both question texts as `['why?','where?']` (this is maked by the comprehension). Then join them: `'why?, where?`